# Why doesn't vendored jQuery load for Sinatra framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm following a tutorial for vendoring jQuery in a Sinatra app and I can't seem to get jQuery to function. I usually use Google's CDN to load jQuery and it works every time but I can't seem to load it by vendoring and I don't know why. I'm more than certain this is something very trivial but I don't see it. Here are the directions I've followed as suggested by my tutorial.

1. Create a public/vendor/jquery.js file
2. Copy and paste the the UNCOMPRESSED jquery 1.11 into jquery.js
3. Create a javascripts/rating.js file and include this code to verify if jquery loaded.

   ```
   $(function(){
     console.log("loaded...");
    });
   ```

When I use the inspect element tool and click on the Network tab, it says that jquery can't be found. What's going on? Oh and this is my index.html.erb file:

```
<body>
<h1>Rate It</h1>

  <div id="rating-container"></div>

   <script src="public/vendor/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="javascripts/rating.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it. The tutorial has a typo in it! Referencing vendor/jquery.js instead of public/vendor/jquery.js worked. Geez.